# TSV input in Hadoop Map Reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to run a simple map reduce operation a TSV dataset and I'm a bit confused about what goes wrong when I'm trying a simple map operation. Following is my modification of the [sample Word Count problem](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/HadoopTutorial/CDH4/Hadoop-Tutorial/ht_wordcount1_source.html) of the map class.

```
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
   private Text node = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
      String line = value.toString();
      String tokens[] = line.split('t');
      node.set(tokens[1]);
      int weight = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
      output.collect(node, new Writable(weight));

    }
  }
```

The input can be visualized as a TSV file having three columns. I get an error `method.java.lang.String.split being not applicable` for the above code in the line where the line is split into tokens. Any ideas where I may be going wrong?

Comment: Try using this: `line.split("\t");` instead of `line.split('t')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String tokens[] = line.split('t');`

Change it to

`String tokens[] = line.split('\t');`

Answer (score 0):

`String tokens[] = line.split('t');`

It should be:

`String tokens[] = line.split("\t");`

Using single-quotes is for char type and would raise an exception.